# Private NuGet gallery not publishing

Tags: nuget

I have set up a NuGet Gallery for use inside my company as per the lengthy instructions at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/contribute/setting-up-a-local-gallery. However I when I push a package to the server it doesn't seem to recognize it even though nuget.exe reports no errors

```
NuGet.exe push -source http://myserver/NuGet-services/FeedService.svc/ publish\mypackage.0.1.nupkg

Pushing MyPackage 0.1 to 'http://myserver/NuGet-services/FeedService.svc/'...
Pushing: 100%
```

The API key is set to what my user has listed on its profile page. I have turned up the logging in the service to DEBUG but nothing at all is printed to the log. I have checked that the service has the ability to write to its data directory and to the database. The packages table in the database is empty as is the directory to which the packages look like they should be published (App_Data/Packages).  If anybody has a suggestion short of attaching a debugger to this thing I would be most interested in your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing to the wrong url. You don't push to the feedservice.svc. The source should be the root (so http://myserver/NuGet-services/ in your case).

Comment: Hi David, I'm having the same issue and I'm pushing correctly to the root url. I'm using IIS, uploading via website works, but not via nuget.exe. Any thoughts about how to troubleshoot?